# Get Excel Range including all shape objects

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

In a VSTO (C#) project I want to take the UsedRange including the shape objects like pictures and charts.

**1. Is there a way to get the UsedRange with shape objects?**

Since I couldn't find such a method, I thought of calculating the edges by using this:

```
foreach (Excel.Shape shape in shapeObjects)
{
     float shapeBottom = shape.Top + shape.Height;
     float shapeRight = shape.Left + shape.Width;
     if (maxBottom < shapeBottom)
     {
         maxBottom = shapeBottom;
     }
     if (maxRight < shapeRight)
     {
         maxRight = shapeRight;
     }
 }

 Excel.Range r = <XXX>(maxBottom, maxRight);
```

So now I have the problem of getting the Range from maxBottom and maxRight.

**2. Is there a way to get a Range object by giving the width and height?**

Comment: Shapes have a `BottomRightCell` property which returns the cell covered by the lower right corner of shape. If you iterate through that property for each shape you should be able to collect the right-most column and the last row for the range you want.  Is the topleft corner of your range fixed?

Comment: Yes, that solves my problem 1 (so no problem 2). Please post as answer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shapes have a BottomRightCell property which returns the cell covered by the lower right corner of shape. 
If you iterate through that property for each shape you should be able to collect the right-most column and the last row for the range you want.